# Life cycle of core data objects and compiler optimization

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have these two helper methods.  With the Optimization Level settings in Xcode to None (default for debug mode), the codes work fine.  But if the Optimization Level is set to anythings other than None, the logs in the testGetAllRecords produced (null).

Any suggestions why it behaves this way?  Did I miss something?

(ARC is being used)

```
+(NSArray *)getAllRecords
{
    NSError *error;
    CoreDataController *coreDataController = [[CoreDataController alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [coreDataController managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group1" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByName, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (Group1 *aGroup in fetchedObjects)
    {
        // This produces valid data
        NSLog(@"getAllRecords name:%@", aGroup.name);
    }

    NSLog(@"getAllRecords currenthread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);   //shown thread num = 1
    return fetchedObjects;
}
+(void)testGetAllRecords
{
    NSLog(@"testGetAllRecords currenthread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);   //shown thread num = 1
    NSArray *allRecords = [DataStoreInterfaceWrapper getAllRecords];
    for (Group1 *aGroup in allRecords)
    {
        //This produces "(null)" when Xcode Optimization Level not set to None
        NSLog(@"testGetAllRecords name:%@", aGroup.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried checking the error parameter that you are passing into the fetch request?

Comment: @Abizern: The logs in the getAllRecords method produced the right data regardless of optimization levels.  So this tells me the fetch operation is working?

Comment: Are you using a temporary context to fetch the managed objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you use a temporary context inside a function mean that it is released at the end of this function, orphaning all managed objects connected to it (turning them to faults with nil context).

With your optimisations on, this happen immediately when your context is no longer retained (at the end of the function), while without optimisations and in "debug" mode, you objects are not released as soon as they are no longer needed.

Use a retained context (one that outlive the scope of the function) and all should be fine.

Comment: If I choose to set my optimization level to None for the submitted app, what are the pitfalls?  (not worry about performance)

Comment: It might not help you in any case. In debug mode there is a "hidden" autorelease pool wrapping execution that objects are retained by it automatically (all objects are added to it upon itialization). this autorelease pool will not exist in a store build and is not part of the optimization level you define.