# IOS app crashing only if installed from app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm having a problem where if I run my app from installing it from the app store it's crashing (On multiple devices). But when I run the exact same code on the device from xCode it works fine.

I've been researching and the only suggestions I can find are to run in Release mode and change Optimization Level to fastest,smallest. Which I tried but it still doesn't crash. Heres the crash log I got:

```
Incident Identifier: 56DF41AE-4A6A-4328-A50E-03B2ECC245F5
CrashReporter Key:   fabdf09dfea5dfb3a78e5ce49b1fda0291703647
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         MobileScripts [356]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/24524BCA-F897-45FE-87E5-3C807733C9C6/MobileScripts.app/MobileScripts
Identifier:      MobileScripts
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-12-12 13:28:29.474 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.5 (10B400)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3195d29e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x395dd97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreData                        0x316fe0d6 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 294
3   CoreData                        0x317566de -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 726
4   MobileScripts                   0x0002ce0a -[XML parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] (XML.m:105)
5   Foundation                      0x3227b28a _endElementNs + 298
6   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x398f3e58 xmlParseEndTag2 + 612
7   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x398f5546 xmlParseTryOrFinish + 1658
8   libxml2.2.dylib                 0x398f4ce8 xmlParseChunk + 208
9   Foundation                      0x32279d66 -[NSXMLParser parse] + 482
10  MobileScripts                   0x0002c664 -[XML parseXml:] (XML.m:32)
11  MobileScripts                   0x00034686 -[WebService parse] (WebService.m:114)
12  Foundation                      0x322986f8 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
13  Foundation                      0x321d81f4 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
14  Foundation                      0x321d8110 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
15  CFNetwork                       0x3163a45a ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 22
16  CFNetwork                       0x31639b3e ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 50
17  CFNetwork                       0x31661fc6 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 14
18  CoreFoundation                  0x318a3748 CFArrayApplyFunction + 172
19  CFNetwork                       0x31662426 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
20  CFNetwork                       0x315c6038 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 184
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3193267e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
22  CoreFoundation                  0x31931ee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
23  CoreFoundation                  0x31930cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
24  CoreFoundation                  0x318a3eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
25  CoreFoundation                  0x318a3d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
26  GraphicsServices                0x354562e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
27  UIKit                           0x337b92fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
28  MobileScripts                   0x0002c58e main (main.m:16)
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x39a14b1c tlv_initializer + 4
```

I see that it doesn't like what I have on line 105 in XML.m, which is just a context save:

```
[context save:&saveError];
```

And like I said this line works just fine when I run it from xcode. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get more information on the exception or make this issue occur while debugging?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**
I watched the device log during the crash and found out the exception is "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'". Any idea as to why this is only happening from the app store?

Comment: Does it crash on your device?

Comment: It crashes on any device that installs the app from the app store. So yes.

Comment: did you release a new version or new app? Tried reinstalling from Appstore?

Comment: @medvedNick It started doing this from the first version, I tried rebuilding and resubmitting in case there was a bug but that didn't work. I also tried reinstalling from the app store with no difference.

Comment: very strange... I can only recommend to install ipa from iTunes (or third party service, like Testflight), to see if you could catch the crash somehow

Comment: If you using a temporary context to fetch the managed objects, then check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945193/life-cycle-of-core-data-objects-and-compiler-optimization

Comment: @user523234 When you say temporary you mean created inside the function? If so the context is a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the device to Xcode or the iPhone configurations program and watch the log.

Also how looks the scope of the save statement. Is there a try catch around it? You have a `NSError` object that should have the info. Usualy it get logged using `NSLog`.

Edit:

Where get the store created path wise and has the device enough room to create the store?

I am taking a guess. Are you delivering the persistence store with your app? Lets say a sqllight  database that is part of the app? You may read files from your app but never write to. You need to move the pre made persistence store to one of the directories you have write access.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I'm getting "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.'". Any idea as to why I'm getting this only from the app store?

Comment: @BrianTacker If you do a clean install in development you probably get the same problem.

Comment: When you say do a clean install you mean remove the app from the device and rerun it from xcode? If so I already tried that.

Comment: Verify the creation of the store, eg the location and device space.

Comment: So I ended up finding out there was an issue when I was using NSAssert during the creation of the persistent store. When I took that out and published the app again it started working. Is there some issue with using NSAssert in the release environment?

Comment: Yes. The purpose for assertion is to have a concrete crash during development instead of running with invalid data. Aasserts shouldnt be in a release build, but it is allways how you deal with errors/exeptions. Have some doubt in all now runnng fine if you only removed the assertion, but thats just a feeling. Personally I am using a cascade of if clauses to make sure the peristnce store gets loqded with q vqlid version.